# generating a jwt token via link using the app router in next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, jwt

i'm trying to export my project from using pages to app router. i having problem when generating jwt token when clicking a link when using the app router. if using nextjs pages, it does work. the suggestion given is to use useRouter from next/navigation but tried that and isnt working. this is  the code i used as below. from browser console it shows error 404 at the line const response = await axios.post('/api/generateToken');. thank you for the help

code:

```
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

    export default function Home() {
    const router = useRouter()

    const handleGenerateToken = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/generateToken', {
        method: 'POST',
      })
      const data = await response.json()
      const { token } = data
      alert(`Generated Token: ${token}`) // show the token in an alert
      const serverUrl = `http://localhost/validate.php?token=${token}`;
      window.location.href = serverUrl;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
   }

   return (
    <div>
      <a href="#" onClick={handleGenerateToken}>Generate Token and Navigate</a>
    </div>
    )
    }
```

the link when clicked will generate a  simple jwt token and send it as part of the URL to another server. when uses pages instead or app router in next.js, its working

Comment: Please show the folder structure of your App router route and aslo add the code you have writen to handle the API request